# Angular 2 e2e using protractor: by.model not working

Tags: angular, model, protractor, angular-e2e

While writing test cases using protractor.js for Angular 2 application , if I want to get `element(by.model("xyz.test"))` its always giving failure saying angular is not defined.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Where do you import `by` from?

Comment: by comes default when writing the test cases http://www.protractortest.org/#/

Comment: If you are using [angular ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/), here is a good solution for this, that I was able to find myself: [ag-grid-access-and-edit-cell-from-protractor-e2e-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219964/ag-grid-access-and-edit-cell-from-protractor-e2e-tests)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by @Carmen Popoviciu, who is one of the contributors to the Protractor style guide, by.model and by.binding are not yet working with Protractor and Angular 2:

> "Keep in mind that currently not all locator strategies are supported
>   for ng2 apps. Things like by.model() or by.binding() are not working
>   just yet. Check the Protractor changelog for new releases"

https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/angular2-go-protractor

Comment: @SnehasisMohapatra, it might not have been the answer you had wish for but if it answers your question for now please mark the question as answered.

Comment: same subject :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814700/failed-unknown-error-angular-is-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment82591605_47814700

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Gabriel Kohen is definitely accurate but I thought I would add another answer with some links to the documentation that actively discourage use of `by.model` and `by.binding`

https://github.com/angular/protractor#compatibility

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#locators

At this point it's probably unlikely they will ever be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a github issue to follow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3205) about this, `by.model` is mentionned in the comments.

(that's the only open ticket I could find at the minute, if anyone has better)