# Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined

Tags: protractor, angular5

i have this error :

```
- Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 4.10.0-20-generic x86_64)
```

when i execute my e2e tests when i use `sendKeys` :

```
return element(by.model('email')).sendKeys('mike@test.test');
```

package.json :

```
{
"name": "app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "build-i18n-dev": "rm -rf dist && for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=dev     ; done",
  "build-i18n-demo": "               for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=demo    ; done",
  "build-i18n-staging": "               for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=staging ; done",
  "build-i18n-qa1": "               for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=qa1     ; done",
  "build-i18n-qa2": "               for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=qa2     ; done",
  "build-i18n-qa3": "               for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=qa3     ; done",
  "build-i18n-prod": "               for lang in ar de en es fr it ja zh; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang --environment=prod    ; done",
  "e2e": "                                                                    ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=dev",
  "e2e-dev": "                                                                ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true  --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=dev",
  "e2e-dev:watch": "                                                          ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4400 --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=dev --live-reload=true",
  "e2e-demo": "   Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=demo",
  "e2e-staging": "Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=staging",
  "e2e-qa1": "    Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=qa1",
  "e2e-qa2": "    Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=qa2",
  "e2e-qa3": "    Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=qa3",
  "e2e-prod": "   Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ng e2e --aot --serve true --port 4200 --watch true --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en --base-href /en/ --output-path /en/ --environment=prod",
  "test": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true",
  "test-dev": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=dev",
  "test-demo": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=demo",
  "test-staging": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=staging",
  "test-qa1": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=qa1",
  "test-qa2": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=qa2",
  "test-qa3": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=qa3",
  "test-prod": "ng test --watch false --single-run true --code-coverage true --colors true --environment=prod",
  "serve-ar": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.ar.xlf --locale=ar --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-de": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.de.xlf --locale=de --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-en": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --locale=en --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-es": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.es.xlf --locale=es --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-fr": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --locale=fr --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-it": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.it.xlf --locale=it --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-ja": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.ja.xlf --locale=ja --i18n-format=xlf",
  "serve-zh": "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.zh.xlf --locale=zh --i18n-format=xlf",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "xi18n": "ng xi18n --outputPath src/locale",
  "doctoc": "doctoc README.md --bitbucket && doctoc doc/README.md --bitbucket --title '**Contents**'",
  "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.ts'"
},
"pre-commit": [
  "doctoc",
  "tslint"
],
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/common": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/core": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/http": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/router": "^5.1.1",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
  "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
  "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
  "core-js": "^2.5.3",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
  "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
  "raven-js": "^3.21.0",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.6.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.1",
  "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.94",
  "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
  "protractor": "^5.2.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
  "tslint": "~5.7.0",
  "typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
```

}

pageLogin.po.ts

```
import { browser, element, by, Key } from 'protractor';


export class PageLoginPo {
    navigateToLogin() {
        return browser.get('/en/login');
    }

    clickToSubmit() {
        return element(by.css('.e2e-btn-submit-sign-in-form')).click();
    }

    setEmail() {
        return element(by.model('email')).sendKeys('mike@test.test');
    }

    setPassword() {
        return element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('mike');
    }

    emptyEmail() {
        return element(by.model('email')).sendKeys('');
    }

    emptyPassword() {
        return element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('');
    }
}
```

pageLogin.e2e-specs.ts

```
import {PageLoginPo} from './pageLogin.po';
import { browser, Key, element, by } from 'protractor';

describe('View Login', () => {
    let page: PageLoginPo;

    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new PageLoginPo();
        page.navigateToLogin();
        browser.waitForAngular();
    });

    });

    it('should display error message when i click on submit sign in form without email', () => {

        page.emptyEmail();
        expect(page.getTextEmailIsRequire()).toEqual('Email is required.');
    });
});
```

Please, can you help me ? thank you for your help :)

Comment: By chance is this old code that recently started failing?  I began making some changes to my project a few days ago and suddenly my `by.model` selectors started failing with that same error.  Seemed like i broke something on my end bc not sure why that would stop working.... but i ended up changing `by.model` to `by.css('[ng-model="modelName"]')` and that removed the error.  Only thing i could think of is I upgraded my chromedriver and browser versions

Comment: you are saved my day !

Comment: by.model and by.binding are not yet working with Protractor and Angular 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077812/angular-2-e2e-using-protractor-by-model-not-working/39861051

Comment: Yea I saw some of those posts, unfortunately my angular version hasnt changed and  I was using `by.model` previously without issue... oh well