# How to locale angular element using by.model in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have this text box element.

`<input type="text" name="textbox" class="box-input ng-pristine ng-scope md-input ng-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-required="field.required" ng-model="$ctrl.model[field.nameField.uuid]" ng-disabled="::field.readOnly" id="input_15" aria-invalid="false" style="">`

In protractor how should I use it to locate the element? I am not quite sure how to use `ng-model="$ctrl.model[field.nameField.uuid]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular 2 or above `by model` might not work for you, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077812/angular-2-e2e-using-protractor-by-model-not-working).

You could still use the model attribute to identify your element through css like so

```
$('[ng-model="$ctrl.model[field.nameField.uuid]"]')
    or
element(by.css('[ng-model="$ctrl.model[field.nameField.uuid]"]'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
let input = element(by.model('$ctrl.model[field.nameField.uuid]'));
```

I suggest to use unique ID if its possible, or some unique class styles leading to single element.